# How to add items incrementally while scrolling in CollectionView in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to add items in `CollectionView` automatically while scrolling in Xamarin Forms. I have an `ObservableCollection<ModelItem>` object as an `ItemsSource` to `CollectionView`. how can I update ItemsSource while scrolling so that items in `CollectionView` also get added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CollectionView`'s `RemainingItemsThreshold` and `RemainingItemsThresholdReached` properties for adding items incrementally to the `CollectionView`.

`RemainingItemsThreshold` is used to fire `RemainingItemsThresholdReached` event whenever specific number of items are remaining to be scrolled in the collection.

Also use `RefreshView` to show refreshing animation while items are added incrementally.

**Here is the XAML code**

```xml
<RefreshView x:Name="refreshView">
    <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView" RemainingItemsThreshold="5" 
                    RemainingItemsThresholdReached="LoadItemsIncrementally"
                    Margin="10" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Margin="5">
                    <Label Text="{Binding ItemName}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</RefreshView>
```

**Here is the C# Code**

```cs
bool isLoading;

public void LoadItemsFirstTimeInCollectionView()
{
    Items = new ObservableCollection<CompanyItem>();
    collectionView.ItemsSource = Items;  // You can use Binding as an ItemsSource in XAML
    refreshView.IsRefreshing = true;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        Items.Add(YourListOrCollection[i]);

    refreshView.IsRefreshing = false;
}

public void LoadItemsIncrementally(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isLoading || Items.Count == 0)
        return;

    isLoading = true;
    int LastItemIndex = Items.Count;

    refreshView.IsRefreshing = true;
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), () => // Fake 2 seconds, Modify with your API call or anything else
    {
        for (int i = LastItemIndex; i < LastItemIndex + 20; i++)
            Items.Add(YourListOrCollection[i]);

        isLoading = false;
        refreshView.IsRefreshing = false;
        return false;
    });
}
```

**[Refer here for official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data)**